# Java - Getting screen position of buffered image

Tags: java, position, screen, bufferedimage

I'm working with some code where I have a few buffered images in a scrollbar. When I click one of these images, I want to draw a rectangle around the image to indicate that the image is selected.

My issue is that because my panel is scrollable, the image position set when drawing is not necessarily the actual screen position. So when the mouse is clicked, the point of the cursor's position doesn't intersect any of the position attributes (x, y, height, & width) I have for the object holding the actual image.

Does anybody know how to get the actual position of an image relative to the screen instead of the panel?
So far I haven't found any solutions to this online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method.

I would guess you need to convert the mouse point the coordinates of the viewport of the scroll pane.

Maybe an easier approach is to use a JList with a custom renderer. You can set the JList to wrap components horizontally. Then in you custom renderer you just add a Border to the selected item. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: +1 and I can only second using a `JList` with renderer for this. :-) Probably a lot easier than managing selection, conversion, painting etc. yourself.